# Free/Open source tool for adding/viewing comments inside HAR files?

Tags: web-development, web-browser, software-testing, logs, network-monitor

I'm looking for a way to provide HAR files to others but with my comments/notes in them so that they will know where in the log file to look for purposes of troubleshooting, etc. Is there a **free/open source tool** that allows one to view/edit HAR files in that way?

Initially I thought HAR files could not possibly store comments in them since I couldn't find a way to do that in Chrome Dev Tools. But, it turns out that with a (paid) application called Charles Proxy one can view, edit and save HAR files, *including comments*. So there must be other apps that can do it as well?

Here is an example of where a comment can be viewed inside a Charles Proxy session (either saved as a HAR file or .chls file):

[image: Screenshot of Charles Proxy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman x9.6 and above has the ability to import HAR files: https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-importing-har-files/

A HAR file is imported as a Postman "collection" and documentation/edits can be added at the individual request level or overall collection level.

Both **free** and paid versions of Postman have this feature. However, at least as of Postman x9.6, support for certain content types (audio/wav, for example) is not supported in the response body of an API call. So in other ways, Postman is not as robust a solution for HAR file viewing as CharlesProxy is.